# Checklist for securing smtp

Tags: smtp

What are some things, one should know when setting up an SMTP server, which supports ESMTP protocol. I have disabled relaying, and only enabled TLS authenticated transfers.
when I telnet to my server, this is the reply:

```
250-mail.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Should any of these be turned off? should anything else be enabled

Comment: Have you tried to send a message through telnet to see if you can relay or if SMTP Authentication is required?

Comment: This looks like a job for the principle of least privilege - disable everything then enable (only) what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the VRFY and / or EXPN these commands can expose user information to people probing a system in preparation for an attack.

Comment: DSN - Delivery Status Notification should be also disabled for the same reasons.

Comment: Depending on the objective of the server it might be better to check which options should be configured about the types of notifications that you wish the others to receive.